# How do I search a range for a single integer?

Tags: python, random, range

My Python code generates a random number between 0 and 35 and stores that number as 'random'. I am looking to compare 'random' against several ranges of numbers to determine which of three groups it falls into and assign another value to 'winning' based on which group 'random' is in. The groups are: 0-16, 16-34, and 34-36. 'winning' always returns 2 though. Here's what I've tried so far.

```
import random #start python random number generator
random = random.randrange(36) #calls a random number between 0-35 and stores value
print random #test

for random in range(0, 16):
   winning = 0
for random in range(16, 34):
   winning = 1
for random in range(34, 36):
   winning = 45
print winning #test
```

Thank you in advance for any help that you can give! This is my first time programming with Python.

Comment: You say: "'winning' always returns 2 though". You must be mistaken. The code that you posted will always print `45`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `if` instead of `for`. `for` is a loop keyword.

```
if random in range(0, 16):
    winning = 0
```

Actually this is not a great use of `range` since it will generate a full list of all numbers and then check each number to see if it equals `random`. It would be more efficient to do some simple comparisons:

```
if 0 <= random < 16:
    winning = 0

# The above is a shorthand syntax for this:
# if 0 <= random and random < 16
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That worked wonderfully, and confirmed my initial guess that if would have worked.

Comment: +0.1 for answering the OPs question, +0.9 for giving a more pythonic (and better in general) solution

Comment: @Kevin: To confirm such a guess, try running the guessed solution.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, please don't name your variable `random`. It shadows the `random` module name and you won't be able to use the `random` module in the rest of scope because of this.

So let's call the result `rnd`.

---

You should use `if rnd in range(0, 16): ...` instead of `for`. The syntax

```
for a in list_:
  foo(a)
```

will extract every element in the `list_` one by one, assign it to `a` each time, then call the body. As seen from [the `for` it is a *loop*](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement). Therefore, you are actually setting `winning = 0` 17 times, etc.

On the other hand, the syntax

```
if b in list_:
  foo(b)
```

which can be seen as

```
if (b in list_):
  foo(b)
```

will check if `b` is an element of `list_`, and execute the body if the condition is true ([the `in` is also an operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#in).)

---

You shouldn't use `in range(...)` to check if a number is in a numeric range because searching in a list takes linear time. The Pythonic way is to use [the `a <= b < c` notation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin):

```
if 0 <= rnd < 16:
  winning = 0
```

But actually it can be written more simply (no matter which language you use) as

```
if rnd < 16:
  winning = 0
elif rnd < 34:
  winning = 1
else:
  winning = 45
```

Answer (score 2):

One implementation of what I think you want:

```
def getWinning(number):
    ranges = {
        0: (0, 16),
        1: (16, 34),
        45: (34, 36)
    }

    for key in ranges :
        low, high = ranges[key]
        if low <= number < high:
            return key
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [bisect.bisect](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) is a nice way to replace the `if` statements:

```
import random 
import bisect

num = random.randrange(36) 
print num 

grid=(0,16,34,36)
winning=bisect.bisect(grid,num)
winning=45 if winning==2 else winning
print(winning)
```

PS. Do not call your random number `random`. Doing so clobbers the module of the same name (making it impossible to call `random.randrange`, say, a second time). This leads to a potentially hard-to-find bug since the exception (`AttributeError`) can occur miles away from the true cause of the error.

Comment: `winning` should be 45, not 2, when the random number is ≥34.

Comment: Ahh...that's why the generator was giving me problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is bit advanced code structure, but really not so much complicated.

```
from random import choice

# Do list weighted by the winning chances
winning=[0]*16+[1]*18+[45]*2

for lottery in range(10):
    win =  choice(winning)
    print("Round %i:\t" % (lottery+1) +
          ("You won $%i" % win if win
           else "No win this time")
          )
```